# push method for reactive form doesn't work properly in angular

Tags: angular

I am using push method to create a pre-filled form for editing something in angular but when I use the push method, It pushed the data in `0` index of the parent.

I use this code:

```
console.log('this is lectures', lectures);

(<FormArray>section.get('lecture')).push(lectures);

console.log('this is lecture of section',section.get('lecture'));

(<FormArray>this.editCourseForm.get('section')).push(section);
```

and the value of each log is like this:

`This is lectures:`

`value: [lecture1, lecture2]`      `//first output`

`This is lecture of section:`

`value: [ [lecture1, lecture2] ]`    `//second output`

I expect the first output and I created all my html form based on first output and the result now in my form is the second output, It has destroyed my for loop in html.

[This](https://gist.github.com/Alavi1412/d9227cc5d340a299f6c735c4dd7a5d78) is my whole code (It is not a big code).

UPDATE 1: lectures is an array of objects

Comment: You are pushing an array to an array, so this is expected behavior. What is `lectures`? Array of string, array of objects?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43675109/6294072

Comment: You probably want to use `concat` not `push`